# AWS Task Token with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

I want to use the RunTask function from the ECS API with step functions to return a result from my ECS tasks. 
In the code that calls RunTask will the code pause and wait until StepFunction gets a success or failure status and would I be able to read the response after the API RunTask call:

```
//code...
var = RunTask(with Task Token...)
//will the program pause until the Task Token gets a response? and

//would I be able to add code here to read the value from the TaskToken?
String = var.TaskToken

//code...
```

Edit:
On AWS webpage(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html) step function integration with ECS RunTask is shown as this:

```
{  
   "StartAt":"Manage ECS task",
   "States":{  
      "Manage ECS task":{  
         "Type":"Task",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken",
         "Parameters":{  
            "LaunchType":"FARGATE",
            "Cluster":"cluster-arn",
            "TaskDefinition":"job-id",
            "Overrides":{  
               "ContainerOverrides":[  
                  {  
                     "Name":"container-name",
                     "Environment":[  
                        {  
                           "Name":"TASK_TOKEN_ENV_VARIABLE",
                           "Value.$":"$$.Task.Token"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "End":true
      }
   }
}
```

I am slightly confused as how I would use this in my golang code. Is there an API that I would pass this into to start the ECS task wioth the state - for example:

```
task = StartTask(THE ABOVE JSON)
```

And would this API allow me to get a response after it performs RunTask in the State:

```
MY_VALUE = task.task_token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call RunTask directly if you are using StepFunctions. [StepFunctions would call ECS on your behalf](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html).

However, if you are getting a task token from StepFunctions through some other means, and then calling RunTask in your own code, then the answer is no. As I stated in the answer to your previous question, RunTask **never** waits for the ECS task to complete. It doesn't even wait for it to start.

So no, whatever code you are writing, wherever it is running, will not wait for an ECS task to complete and return a response after calling RunTask. That's why you want StepFunctions to manage the ECS task for you, because StepFunctions will pause the state machine (if you have it configured to run the task in `waitForTaskToken` mode) and wait for your ECS task to [issue a callback to StepFunctions with the task token once it is done](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token).

Comment: Okay, I thought I would use RunTask and input this in the RunTask definition: IntegrationPattern: sfn.integrationPattern_WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN. Instead are you saying I should be calling create a new state machine from an API and pass in the configs that I have from my RunTask as input? Does the API allow me to create a state machine in my code and pass in the needed params?

Comment: My original thought from above came from here - npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks#runtask. So I assumed the response of RunTask would wait and I would be able to get the output with updated task token. I think im just a little confused now - in my code that calls RunTask should I replace that with something else? Do I have to make the StateMachine First and then run it with RunTask? I've edited the question a little to explain where i think im a little lost

Comment: You can't directly call the ECS RunTask API and pass it `IntegrationPattern: sfn.integrationPattern_WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN` because you wouldn't have a task token to pass it. You should define an AWS StepFunctions state machine once, not every time you want to run a task. You would trigger an execution of the state machine each time you want to run the task.

Comment: One of the steps in the state machine would be to run an ECS task, and StepFunctions would pass the task token to that task when it runs it, and then pause the state machine until your code in your ECS task specifically makes a call to the StepFunctions API to pass the task token back, letting StepFunctions know it should continue the state machine.

Comment: The code you linked is to the AWS CDK, which doesn't even directly run a task, it just compiles into an AWS CloudFormation template, which you would then apply to create your infrastructure.

Comment: To be clear, if you are using StepFunctions you would not be calling the AWS ECS RunTask API yourself at all. You would be calling the StepFunctions API to trigger an existing state machine. Part of that state machine's definition would include the "Manage ECS task" step that you just added to your question. AWS StepFunctions would manage your ECS task, and wait for some code in your ECS task to pass the task token back into the StepFucntions API.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I’ll play around with the step function api to try and invoke runtask in the state machine

Comment: Hey Mark so I followed what you told me - I created a state machine and am running start execution with the ARN. Everything works perfectly but to get the task token output I have to run a while loop that looks at the state machines status - if its running we keep looping. I saw another function start_sync_execution but I get an error that the state machine is not supported because I am using async task token state machine. Do you if there is a way to work around this so I can get rid of the while loop I am using or is this not possible. Thanks

Comment: There is no way to run a docker container like this and wait for output without something like a while loop. That's why I said in your previous question that AWS Lambda is more suited to the task you are trying to perform.

Comment: Makes sense - thank you for you help and guidance again Mark